# Extracting a mid-plane for thick shell analysis

Tags: computational-geometry, solid-mechanics, shells

I have a complex part that contains features of the form shown in the figure below.

[image: hollow shell]

Because of the cost of 3D finite element simulation of the part, I want to try an analysis with 2D thick shells.

However, I am running into a problem when trying to extract the mid-surface of the part.  Automated tools provide me with a mid-surface that is shown by the red dashed line in the figure.  That leads to interpenetration of the top and bottom surfaces in bending.

I would like a mid-surface that is shown by the green dashed line.

Can anyone point me to automated mid-surface extraction algorithms that can do what I seek?

Comment: Did you try computing the alpha shape of the section?

Comment: No, I've only use commercial tools so far.  But I'll look up what alpha shape means.  Also, I'm not dealing with something that can be termed a section.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you if you don't tell us in what format you have the geometry.

Comment: I guess, think that my suggestion might not be useful. For some reason, I mixed alpha shapes with polygon skeletonization.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth:  That's intriguing.  Could you explain why?  I would have though that the format doesn't matter.   I can store the geometry either as topological entities (points, curve, curve loops, surfaces, surface loops, volumes) or as triangulated surfaces.  And save the geometry is a number of file formats, STEP (topological) is the most convenient.

Comment: My comment is based on the fact that clearly the tool you're using is not seeing the information as it is, and I'm trying to figure out why that would be so. Some descriptions might be more suitable than others. For example a description of just the black lines without any information about what the enclosed volume is, would not be very helpful.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: The original  hollow geometry is probably being generated by skinning an external surface with SolidWorks and then removing overlapping surfaces.  That's my best guess.  I've recreated the geometry in gmsh and see the same medial axis problem with Cubit.

Comment: Then I suspect that in your geometry, the midplane of the middle part is actually marked as a boundary of the object.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth:  That's what I suspected and led to my redoing the model in gmsh to get rid of such issues (there is no middle boundary in the gmsh model).  Since I can't reason about black box algorithms, I need to write it myself.  Hence, the original question.